# Validate Multiple Form on the same page at once with a single button click with jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Is validation of multiple form with jquery validator possible with a single button clicked. If yes how can it be done

Code that I've done so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('button.validateAll').click(function(){
            $('form').each(function(){
                $(this).validate({
                        rules:{
                            title:{
                                required:true,
                                minlength:5
                            }                            
                        },
                        submitHandler: function(form){
                                return true;
                        }
                });
            });
        });
```

});

Comment: If you are are going validate multiple forms with single button then why your are creating multiple forms in the first place? keep all the fields in single form and on submit validate all the field.

Comment: I am creating a system where user can add forms dynamically and post them with a single button click @ShrikantMavlankar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of the `.validate()` method...

```
$('button.validateAll').click(function(){
    $('form').each(function(){
        $(this).validate({...
```

The `.validate()` method merely initializes the plugin on your form.  If you want validation to work when the user is filling out the form, then you must initialize the plugin as soon as your form is loaded, not when the button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).validate({...
```

To validate all forms on the page with one button click requires a custom `click` handler and the `.valid()` method...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.validateAll').click(function() {
        $('form').each(function() {
            $(this).valid();
        });
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/gdchtpjf/](http://jsfiddle.net/gdchtpjf/)**